# Online questionnaires in R where answers can be conveyed among users

Tags: r, survey

Is there any R-package to build an online questionnaire with multiple-choice and open-ended questions whose answers can be conveyed from one user to another? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This is specifically [off-topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow, so will likely be closed shortly. (I know of no package that provides that functionality offhand.)

Comment: This is offtopic on SO, but what does "whose answers can be conveyed from one user to another" mean? Do you want users to be able to share/see/edit/copy/revise each others' answers?

Comment: My idea is to simulate a little social network, where each person can share answers to open-ended questions only with those this person wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use Survey Monkey for the survey itself and the Rmonkey package (https://github.com/cloudyr/Rmonkey) to analyze and report the survey results. With this approach, the user must have a Survey Monkey account, a Mashery Survey Monkey Developer account, and a registered API application.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Walker. I will try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use limesurvey, which is free if you have a host server. With the package limer, you can import the responses to R.

Comment: Great. Thank you, José.